# Training a neural network to compute 'XOR' in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to learn how to use scikit-learn's MLPClassifier. For a very simple example, I thought I'd try just to get it to learn how to compute the XOR function, since I have done that one by hand as an exercise before.

However, it just spits out zeros after I try to fit the model.

```
xs = np.array([
    0, 0,
    0, 1,
    1, 0,
    1, 1
]).reshape(4, 2)

ys = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0]).reshape(4,)

model = sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier(
    activation='logistic', max_iter=10000, hidden_layer_sizes=(4,2))
model.fit(xs, ys)

print('score:', model.score(xs, ys)) # outputs 0.5
print('predictions:', model.predict(xs)) # outputs [0, 0, 0, 0]
print('expected:', np.array([0, 1, 1, 0]))
```

I put my code in a jupyter notebook on github as well https://gist.github.com/zrbecker/6173ac01ed30be4eea9cc96e21f4896f

Why can't scikit-learn come to a solution, when I can show explicitly that one exists? Is the cost function getting stuck in a local minimum? Is there some kind of regularization happening on the parameters that force them to stay close to 0? The parameters I used were reasonably large (i.e. -30 to 30).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears a logistic activation is the root cause here.

Change your activation to either `tanh` or `relu` (my favourite). Demo:

```
model = sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier(
    activation='relu', max_iter=10000, hidden_layer_sizes=(4,2))
model.fit(xs, ys)
```

Outputs for this model:

```
score: 1.0
predictions: [0 1 1 0]
expected: [0 1 1 0]
```

It's always a good idea to experiment with different network configurations before you settle on the best one or give up altogether.

Comment: Nice that does it. However, in my manual setup I used 1/(1 + e^(-z)) for my activation function. That is the logistical function, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is indeed sigmoid. What could the root cause be? Well, underflow is a possible explanation.

Comment: @zrbecker Overflow is also possible, if you're setting large parameters.

Comment: Tried the code, `relu` gives random predictions but `tanh` always gives correct result

Answer (score 1):

Actually the point here is about 'solver' which is by default = 'adam' and works well for large data sets. Bigger 'alpha' should also improve:

```
MLPClassifier(activation='logistic', max_iter=100, hidden_layer_sizes=(3,), alpha=0.001, solver='lbfgs', verbose = True)
```

And by the way it's possible to solve this issue with only 3 elements in one  hidden layer with

Answer (score 0):

The following is a simple example of XOR classification by sklearn.neural_network

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn.neural_network

inputs = np.array([[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]])
expected_output = np.array([0,1,1,0])

model = sklearn.neural_network.MLPClassifier(
                activation='logistic',
                max_iter=100,
                hidden_layer_sizes=(2,),
                solver='lbfgs')
model.fit(inputs, expected_output)
print('predictions:', model.predict(inputs))
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a magic sequence of parameters to allow the model to infer correctly from the data it hasn't seen before? None of the solution mentioned above doesn't seem to work.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier

# clf = RandomForestClassifier(random_state=0)
# clf = MLPClassifier(activation='logistic', max_iter=100, hidden_layer_sizes=(2,), alpha=0.001, solver='lbfgs', verbose = True)
clf = MLPClassifier(
                activation='logistic',
                max_iter=100,
                hidden_layer_sizes=(2,),
                solver='lbfgs')
X = [[ 0,  0],  # 2 samples, 3 features
     [0, 1],
#      [1, 0],
    [1, 1]]
y = [1, 
     0,
#      1,
     1]  # classes of each sample
clf.fit(X, y)

assert clf.predict([[0, 1]]) == [0]
assert clf.predict([[1, 0]]) == [0]
```